# using = inside bquote

Tags: r, metaprogramming, non-standard-evaluation

```r
a <- "A"
bquote(.(as.name(a)) = 4)
```

`Error: unexpected '=' in "bquote(.(as.name(a)) ="`

```r
bquote(A = 4)
```

`Error in bquote(A = 4) : unused argument (A = 4)`

```r
a <- "A"
bquote(f(.(as.name(a)) = 4))
```

`Error: unexpected '=' in "bquote(f(.(as.name(a)) ="`

How can I get around this?

Comment: I'm AFK but try `bquote(expr = .(as.name(a)) = 4)` I think it should work. Else try `bquote('=' (.(as.name(a)), 4))`.

Comment: Is this to create an expression for `plotmath`? Then you want a double equals `==`, not a single one. Or are you trying to create an assignment expression? Here's another case where using `<-` would work better than `=`

Answer (score 1):

We don't need `as.name`

```
plot(1, 1, main = bquote(.(a) == 4))
```

-output

[image]

---

or another option with quotes

```
plot(1, 1, main = bquote(.(a)~'= 4'))
```